# Is it possible to create shortcut to a page in a Word or pdf file?

Tags: windows-10, filesystems, shortcuts, file-shortcut

Looks like one can create a link to open a particular page in a pdf file as described here: https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/link-html-pdf-page-acrobat.html. Is it possible to create a shortcut to a particular page in a MS-Word or pdf file in Windows 10? So, if one creates a desktop shortcut to a file as written in [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-desktop-shortcut-for-an-office-program-or-file-9a8df64b-cd87-4700-95cc-4bc3e2a962da), the shortcut will open a particular page of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For A word document, There are [no Command line Switches for opening a particular page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/command-line-switches-for-microsoft-office-products-079164cd-4ef5-4178-b235-441737deb3a6), So I don't think that would be possible without an extremely clever solution. However, that can not be said for PDFs:

1. If you want to open via Acrobat Reader/Foxit Reader/pdf-xchange, this command seems to work:

```
<path to Adobe Reader> /A "page=100" "<Path To PDF file>"
```

Create a **New Shortcut** on the desktop. Paste this command there. This also works with pdf-Xchange and Foxit Reader.

2. If you want to open it via Chrome/Firefox/Any similar browser:

```
<path to browser> "file:///<File Location>#page=100"
```